# How can I get file path in some Java package?

Tags: java

I am new at Java. I got a file in my jasper.deneme package. I want to give a full path for it. As can be seen in the picture I write it like

```
string fullpath = "/jasper.deneme/reportDeneme.jasper";
```

but it does not work.

So how can I get this file's path?

[Java Package http://img250.yukle.tc/images/3464package.jpg](http://img250.yukle.tc/images/3464package.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`denemeJasper.class.`[`getResource`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))`("reportDeneme.jasper").`[`getPath`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath())`()`

If you need the path for reading the file's contents, it would be simpler (and safer) to use `getResourceAsStream()` and avoid having to deal with paths entirely.

BTW, your class `denemeJasper` violates ubiquitous Java naming standards; as a class, its name should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

The might be better off with a relative path, but the absolute path would be:

```
String fullpath = "/jasper/deneme/reportDeneme.jasper";
```

`'/'` replaces `'.'` in the package name whether the resource is located in a file, a jar or by any other means.